# POSTFIX - Trigger script when user login

Tags: php, smtp, postfix-mta, pam, dovecot

I tried to google for solution for me, but it seems impossible to find it. I am running server with php + mysql + mail server. I would like to know, how is possible to trigger PHP script when user is login to SMTP with email address and password.

So example: User setup email@email.com and password: password in thunderbird. Now user create email and click on send. Thunderbird is logging to postfix - and at this point i want to know how is possible to run PHP script and get arguments into it such as email and password. This way i would be able to create script, script will check if password was entered OK and if there was 5 failed logins IP adress will be blocked by this script for next hour.

No problem for me to create this script. Problem is how to make dovecot / postfix to send credentilas to my php script and ask my PHP script if its okay or no.

The only driver i can found was: PAM, MYSQL but its useless for me. So how can be this done? Thanks for your answers !

Comment: There is a filter you can install without re-inventing the wheel: [link]https://importgeek.wordpress.com/2017/01/15/fail2ban-prevent-postfix-brute-force/

Comment: Fail2Ban cant do what i want. I need to do some summaries, some logs, block ip adresses etc. So i need parse data from postfix to php script while login.

Comment: Fail2Ban does have action hooks that you can tap into. Here's a sample that can call a PHP script .... : [link]https://www.savjee.be/2015/09/Sending-fail2ban-notifications-and-others-to-slack-chat-channel/  See section: **Configure fail2ban**

Comment: Stil is not realtime - its just read logs. I just need exactly know how to process login process in php